# MYSQL not returning the result in the linux platform, but in windows

Tags: java, mysql, linux, hibernate, tomcat

I am running the above code as a webapp in tomcat from within eclipse.

The project is running fine on the windows platform and now I have migrated it to Linux(OpenSuse 12.3), and the following code is returning the user from the mysql DB.

```
@Override
public User getUserByLoginID(String userLogin) {
    log.info("getUserByLoginID(String userLogin)");
    User returnUser = null;
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class).add(
            Restrictions.eq("userLoginEmail", userLogin));
    if (criteria.list() != null) {
        List<User> users = criteria.list();

        if (users.size() > 1) {
            // Should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Invalid number of users with same login id.");
        }
        if (!users.isEmpty()) {
            returnUser = users.get(0);
        }
    }
    return returnUser;
}
```

I have checked the following line, `users.size()`and it gives the result in the window, but notin OpenSuse/Linux.

I have installed mysql on both the machines.
The user exists in both the databases.

I am suspecting that I may have to configure some user/group configuration for the mysql DB.
Any idea, how can I further debug, troubleshoot?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try connection to db on Windows from your linux platform from java code. See if it is fetching data. If yes, then db on your linux platform is not set correctly.

Comment: Database names are case sensitive on the linux platform and case insensitive when using windows. Make sure that the database name that is used for your java queries matches the one that exists inside the DBMS.

Comment: @f1sh, the databse name cases are correct, because tomcat is able to connect to the database, otherwise it would throw exceptions when it starts up.

Comment: @f1sh, database  name case was correct, but the table name case was different, but the issue was that when I was running as a user, no exception was thrown in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the different inputs.
database  name case was correct, but the table name case was different, but the issue was that when I was running the application as a user, no exception was thrown in the logs.

I logged in as root and tried to run the application as root user, and that's when I could see the exception in the logs, which prompted me in the right direction.